# Build,Hudson,SVN,Jboss

Tags: java, svn, jboss, jakarta-ee, hudson

I have Hudson configured in Tomcat. And I build the application using the Hudson.
I also want to configure the Jboss Server using the Hudson, so that after the buld, Jboss automatically takes the new build and restart the server.

One more, How can I get the war file link on my Hudson link which is build on Linux server, so that I can download the same.

Comment: How do you create your war file? Maven ?

Answer (score 0):

When you know the created artifact, you could just copy it over into JBoss and have it hot deployed there. Hudson allows for custom commands to be run after a job - this would apply here.